# jQuery check link

Tags: jquery, target

**1)** We have a page `index.html` with blocks:

```
<body>
<div id="action1">One</div>
<div id="action2">Two</div>
<div id="action3">Three</div>
</body>
```

**2)** CSS

```
body div { color: blue; }
body div.current { font-weight: bold; color: red; }
```

**3)** Other pages with links to `index.html` and some target:

```
<a href="index.html#action1">Link to One</a><br/>
<a href="index.html#action2">Link to Two</a><br/>
<a href="index.html#action3">Link to Three</a><br/>
```

---

The question is **how to catch current link target** on page `index.html` and give extra class for target block.

If current link of opened page is `index.html#action1`, then add class `.current` to `<div id="action1">One</div>`- will become `<div id="action1" class="current">One</div>`

If `index.html#action2`-> `<div id="action2" class="current">Two</div>`

And so on.

- check #`target`
- check `id`
- if `target` = `id` addClass("current") for block with `id`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(function() {
  if(location.hash) $(location.hash).addClass("current");
});
```

This uses the [location's `hash` property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) (if there is one), it'd be `"#action1"` as an [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) then adds the class via [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), short and simple :)

Comment: hot to remove "#" from value?

Comment: @Happy - You wouldn't want to if you're using it as a selector, you *want* that `#` prefix.  If you need the value for something else, just call `location.hash.replace('#','')`